# Animation in CSS3 with JS trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a problem that when you use the function to rotate the blue square you can only use it once. After that you'll have to reload the page in order to be able to use the rotate function once again.
Also, when you have rotated 120degrees by clicking once, the square then resets itself and goes back to starting position.

So I need help with two things.

1. Fix so you can click the rotation function multiple times and it keeps rotating.
2. Prevent the square from reseting it's position.

I made a fiddle out of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/kv7may8t/2/

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateright');
});
```

Summarize of function:
Hit button1 to trigger function adding class "rotateright" to the blue square which makes it rotate 120degrees.

Comment: You can use jQuery animations.

Comment: I prefer to solve this task with JS and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of first thing remove class will fix your first issue:

```
var bluediv = document.getElementById('blue')

bluediv.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
bluediv.classList.remove('rotateright');
      bluediv.classList.remove('rotateleft');
});
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kv7may8t/30/) (You can click the rotation function multiple times and it keeps rotating. - Solved)

And Answer for second thing is(apply in right only):

Use: `animation-iteration-count: forwards;`

Check [Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/kv7may8t/35/) (Prevent the square from resetting it's position- Solved)

Comment: Both fiddles is behaving as the original code. The cube are still reseting it's position and you can't click multiple times.

Comment: @Winterwind Sorry i make it only for firefox browser support i update it with webkit support. please check fiddle link again.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now.
One last question though. Whenever I try to run the code from dreamweaver -> localhost -> google chrome, nothing happens. Any ideas why?

Comment: Make sure you applied all webkit animation inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
   var degrees +=120;
   var time = 4;
   document.getElementById('blue').style.WebkitTransitionDuration= time + "s";
   document.getElementById('blue').style.transform = "rotate(" +degrees + "deg)";
});
```

To adjust change degrees and duration.

Comment: It works. But the smooth animation is gone. Is it possible to adjust?

Comment: Never use CSS styles with javascript, it impact on performance alot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct just need some modification, you are using transform, when you add class it rotates that div. You just need to remove class before adding it.
Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/kv7may8t/15/).
Use this code

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.remove('rotateright');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateright');    
    },100)

});

document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.remove('rotateleft');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateleft');        
    },100)
});


document.getElementById('button3').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('red').classList.add('animate');
});

document.getElementById('button4').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('red').classList.remove('animate');
});
```

**Don't forget to use setTimeout as after removal class, it needs some time. So use setTimeout and then add class.**

Comment: Two things, one is that both the left and right rotation resets itself after the animation is completed and the cube is back to standard position. Second, if you have clicked rotateleft you can't click rotateright without uploading the page. Which numbers should I add to setTimeout?

Comment: you can remove retotaleft also on rotateright button click. 100 ms is good enough to wait to add class, you can check with fiddle which i provided

Comment: Yeh, I adjusted and it works good. Now I can spam both ways. But, they are still reseting their positions after each animation.